# QGIS 3.34 core plugin SAGA GIS provider defect, missing metadata file (OSGeo4W)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, osgeo4w

I updated QGIS to the new version via OSGeo4W Setup. Everything worked fine, but when I check plugins, the sagaprovider core plugin shows an error message, that the plugin is defect and the metadata file is missing.

I tried to reinstall QGIS, install qgis-ltr-full meta package and saga 7 / 9 with the OSGeo4W Setup, but nothing fixed the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!

**tl;dr**
Got to `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins` (or wherever you installed it) and remove the `sagaprovider` folder.

Since the sagaprovider plugin has been removed earlier, it should not be there anymore. When I started the latest version (3.36.0), the sagaprovider plugin error was not there. So I researched a bit and found out, that this error exists since version 3.30 (https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/780) and just in OSGeo4W as it seems.

Then there was a fix, that deletes the old directory when updating (https://github.com/jef-n/OSGeo4W/commit/c44fb7651a5c2edebdb03f8dbb526f6b0dcc4cd5), but just for the latest version, not the ltr.

For using the SAGA tools, you now have to install the *Processing Saga NextGen Provider* plugin I guess (and don't forget to install SAGA 9 with the OSGeo4W Setup).